# Log php code from php extension

Tags: php, php-extension

I'm trying to make some custom measurement on php code execution. It includes many aspects like: execution time, "includes" count, code behavior.. etc.
I decided to build a php extension, but there is one task that I have no idea how to fulfill it, that is :

**How to log the executed code as it.** I mean, how to print out the measured php code as php text.

Other information: I'm developing under windows 7 using VC++, apache and php5.3 .

Comment: Have you heard of [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/)?

Comment: Not really. Do you think I it could help?

Comment: Well, it's a PHP extension for debugging and profiling code. Since its features partly overlap with yours, you do not need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thank you very much @ComFreek, It seems to be very useful. but i'm afraid of diving in the code of a complex general purpose extension for -maybe- my simple requirements.